# Programmatically determining version of ArcGIS API for Python?

Tags: python, arcgis-python-api

I would like to obtain the version of ArcGIS API for Python for logging/diagnostic purposes.

Is there a way to determine this before a connection is made?

I know that once I have the `GIS` object, I can obtain the [version](https://esri.github.io/arcgis-python-api/apidoc/html/arcgis.gis.toc.html#arcgis.gis.GIS.version) but I seek a way to obtain that information earlier in the script.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear. You're asking about the version of the ArcGIS API for Python, but from context, it seems you are interested in finding the version of the portal you are connecting to (this is what you get from the GIS object). Can you clarify?

Comment: No, this question is for the API itself. So your comment on @raskar-kapak's answer is actually the answer I was after.  Which I thought I had tried and received `None`, but it is working this morning so I must have had a typo or something.  If you modify your answer (which I think makes some good points for future readers of this q&a) with your comment, I'll accept it.

Comment: And the use case for this would be to when I provide a script to the customer and it doesn't work on their machine for some reason, I'll know what version API they are running from the log file.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Update based on OP's comment:

To get the version of the ArcGIS API for Python package, the following snippet should work without first establishing a connection:

```
import arcgis
arcgis.__version__
```

on my machine outputs

```
'1.5.2'
```

*looks like I need to upgrade*

If you wish to find the version without even importing arcgis at all, Raskar Kapak's answer would be a good choice.

If you are looking for the version of the portal you are going to connect to, you can't really know it before connecting. But you can make a connection with a less heavy package than `arcgis`and without authenticating against the portal. You would simply use any library of your choosing that can make a POST request. If you make a POST request with the parameter `f=json` against the URL `<portalurl.com>/sharing/rest`, you will receive the following JSON response indicating the portal version:

```
{"currentVersion":"7.1"}
```

Answer (score 2):

The following code is working perfectly for me.

```py
import pkg_resources

dists = [d for d in pkg_resources.working_set]
for el in dists:
    if "arcgis" in str(el):
        arcVersion=str(el).split(" ")[1]
print(arcVersion)
```

Hope it helps. Cheers.